Is there any way to sort folders by the file type inside them?
I am using XFCE Ubuntu Linux to organize a large collection of media. Among these files are folders containing .pdf files, folders containing .mp3 files, and folders containing .m4b files. Is there anyway to group the folders according to the file type within so that they can be categorized into folders with the labels music, audiobooks, ebooks, etc.?
A solution within the CLI or a GUI would be appreciated.
Ideally I would like to keep each file in its corresponding folder, so that audiobooks in the .mp3 format would not be sent to the music folder, or vice versa.

Are you talking about a GUI or a CLI option? Please edit the question w/ additional info.

Find for eg all the mp3s and move them to a specific folder? find . -type f -name "*.mp3" -exec mv {} ~/Music/ \;?

What will the directory names be and what are the filenames  and how is which of the latter are to be moved into the former determined? Edit the question and add that information. Also, what have you tried and what isn't functioning? You aren't required to provide that but you are far more likely to receive help if you give an effort as this isn't a service to write scripts.

By "file type", do you mean "filename suffix"? A file type in Unix are things like regular file, named pipe, socket, directory, and symbolic link.

How would you suggest one would determine whether one audio file is an audio book, some music, a voice note, or a radio show?
